# Changing content of a character column based on its row value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a categorical column in my dataframe with 14 different string possibilities. I want to create a new variable that only retain 3s strings and collapses all remaining strings into "other".

I thought of doing this by first creating a vector which has the row numbers where one of the 3 categories appear then combining these:

```
x <- which(binarydata1$Sector=="Independent artist")
y <- which(binarydata1$Sector=="Arts and Culture")
z <- which(binarydata1$Sector=="Community or Social Services")
object <- c(x, y, z) #This contains all the row values of the strings listed, the ones I don't want to change ....
```

Can I use this somehow to call the row values in the column that are NOT equal to these values, so that I can replace those strings with Other? Or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: Please post representative data to work with.  You can do this using `dput(bindarydata1)`, or `dput` on some subset of the data that contains the `Sector` values you are interested in.  See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a simple `ifelse`?

```r
values <- c("Independent artist", "Arts and Culture", "Community or Social Services")
x <- ifelse(binarydata1$Sector %in% values,
            binarydata1$Sector,
            "Other")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forcats::fct_other` which will keep only the values that you specify and change rest of them to "Other".

```
binarydata1$Sector <- forcats::fct_other(binarydata1$Sector, 
                      keep = c("Independent artist", 
                              "Arts and Culture","Community or Social Services"))
```